# CUDA driver version is higher than the CUDA runtime version？

Tags: python-3.x, cuda, pytorch

The terminal shows the error:

```
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (35) : CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version at torch/csrc/cuda/Module.cpp:51
```

But my driver version (440.118.02) is sufficient for cuda9.0

Some info about my machine: cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module 440.118.02 Thu Sep 3 09:54:46 UTC 2020

```
cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt CUDA Version 9.0.176
```

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade the CUDA version to 9.2 or higher. After getting the new CUDA just check driver version 440 is still compatible or not. If not upgrade that too.

Do these and then run your code and check.

NOTE: If you have installed or upgraded the Nvidia driver or CUDA recently then reboot the system once and then try.

Comment: thank for your answer~ I will try it first, then give you the result. Thank again